Jakarta Security documentation for RESTful Web Services application
I'm trying to implement authentication on a Jakarta RESTful (Edit: Jakarta EE 9.1 running in a TomEE WebProfile 9.1.x) application using Jakarta Security specification.
I first tried using the @BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition annotation on an @ApplicationScoped annotated class implementing IdentityStore but nothing appened (no basic authentication prompt nor resource denied).
// FooIdentityStore.java

@ApplicationScoped
@BasicAuthenticationMechanismDefinition
public class FooIdentityStore implements IdentityStore {}

//FooResource.java

@Path("foo")
@DenyAll
public class FooResource {
  @GET
  public String get() {
    return "Hello world!";
  }
}

After many researches I found a Jakarta tutorial telling this:

If your web application does not use a servlet, however, you must specify a security-constraint element in the deployment descriptor file. The authentication mechanism cannot be expressed using annotations, so if you use any authentication method other than BASIC (the default), a deployment descriptor is required.
Getting Started Securing Web Applications > Specifying Security Constraints

But I'm not able to find a relative paragraph to this assertion in any documentation of the Jakarta Specification, not in "Servlet", nor in "RESTful Web Services", nor in "Security".
Does anyone know where I can find such a paragraph please ?

Oh yes, so sorry... My application is based on Jakarta EE 9.1 and running in a TomEE WebProfile 9.1.x.
